# Sharing mac files vmware fusion

Tags: file-sharing

I have Ubuntu running on VMWare Fusion on my Macbook Pro. I can't seem to access files on the Mac. I have tried looking into /mnt/hgfs but there is nothing there. I have been to settings and said that it should share certain folders on the Mac to no avail.